# Getting value out of key value pairs of AJAX POST request in asp.net web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hello there you can see in the screen shot that i receive key value pairs through my ajax post request but i dont know that how should i decode them in my web method.

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Get_Data(string funcParam)
    {
        return "";
    }
```

[image: My key value pair]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object in javascript and send it to the `[WebMethod]` using `JSON.stringify()`.The object will automatically be de-serialized to a C# class in the code behind.

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class CallingWebMethodFromJS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Get_Data(Parameters parameters)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        return "";
    }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnOK").click(function () {
                var parameters =
                    {
                        "Value1": $("#value1").val(),
                        "Value2": $("#value2").val(),
                        "Value3": $("#value3").val(),
                    };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "CallingWebMethodFromJS.aspx/Get_Data",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ parameters: parameters }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function (errordata) {
                        alert('failure');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" id="value1" />
        <input type="text" id="value2" />
        <input type="text" id="value3" />
        <input type="button" value="OK" id="btnOK" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Debug your javascript and tell me what the error is?I have a page called CallingWebMethodFromJS.aspx and inside that page I have a [WebMethod] called Get_Data if your setup is not the same you will get an error.If you don't have 3 text boxes in your html with IDs value1 value2 and value3 you will also get an error.Debug your javascript in the browser console

Comment: the error is gone but is there a way in which i can use FormCollection built in class to receive form?

Comment: What for?Using a strongly typed C# class is much better and less prone to errors than FormCollection which is a NameValueCollection

Answer (score 0):

If you get that value in WebMethod. **split** your result by **"&"**. so you have list of **key** and **value** pair.

**OR** : **Deserialize JSON**

**Pass Json** as String and **convert** that JSON to any **list of class** (deserialize) again

Comment: but thats not a good solution ? and how to do it with multiple pairs?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 JObject o = JObject.Parse(funcParam);

 string value1= (string)o["textbox1"];
```